# Amazon AWS - Changing Security Group for EC2s after ASG creates them

Tags: amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

**What I am doing now**

1. I have an Auto Scaling Group (ASG) which utilizes launch config
2. As part of the above launch config, I have mentioned a security group for EC2 which will have open ingress/egress i.e. everything.
3. Also, I will run some user data script.

** The problem **
4. I want to attach my ASG to my existing ELB - `test_elb`

5. `test_elb` has Security Group Ingress/Egress rule

   - From 0.0.0.0/0 at port 80 - Ingress
   - To "Security Group X" port 4463 - Egress

My question/doubt

1. How do I make sure that ASG can create the EC2 instance and attach it as part of `test_elb`, honour my security group `Security Group X`

Answer (score 0):

Ok - jumped the gun but this is what I did to get it to work

1. I created a new security group with only outbound rule - `SG-xyz`
2. Then, I attached it to my launch template along with other SGs
3. I continued with ASG creation and attached the ELB - it was successful and I saw the new instance created - and verified with SSH cxn (only from my IP)
4. Checked the `test_elb` target list - and the new server has been added.
5. fired the request on browser by using ALB DNS - it worked and showed my landing page!